# Masonry plain ol' not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm rolling my own DB-less photo gallery ([live here](http://custom.element17.com)), and would like to use Masonry to lay out thumbnails without a lot of white space (though this is more like "grey space" on my site).

I believe I'm implementing it correctly:

```
var $container=$('#main');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector : '.box',
                columnWidth: 200
            });
        });
```

Perhaps one issue is that I'm using another piece of code to round the edges of the thumbnails:

```
$("img.rounded_corners").each(function() {
            $(this).wrap('<div class="box rounded_corners" />');
            var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
            var imgHeight = $(this).height();
            var imgWidth = $(this).width();
            $(this).parent()
                .css("background-image", "url(" + imgSrc + ")")
                .css("background-repeat","no-repeat")
                .css("background-color","#fff")
                .css("height", imgHeight + "px")
                .css("width", imgWidth + "px");
            $(this).remove();
        });
```

This basically replaces the images with divs, which I have added the appropriate "box" class to.

Still, the layout on the page remains unchanged regardless of what I do.  What's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the second JS code, the masonry works?

Comment: I've checked your page with console opened, masonry plugin is throwing an error

Comment: Oh, okay... What is the error?

Comment: Error thrown at line 9, column 1670 in <anonymous function>(a, b) in http://custom.element17.com/js/masonry.min.js:
    l.style.marginTop="1%",k.appendChild(l);
called from line 9, column 0

Comment: Any idea what that means?  How can there be an error in the plugin code itself?

Comment: Try getting and older version and see if that works, or if the same version works on a different version of jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now got it... I don't know how I haven't seen this before

It's not an bug with masonry / jQuery version

The script that was wrapping all the images in the `.box` div was running before the images was loaded in the document. So, nothing was selected, and when masonry script run, there was no element with `box` class.

So, move the last script to the end of the body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            Shadowbox.init();
            $("img.rounded_corners").each(function() {
                $(this).wrap('<div class="box rounded_corners" />');
                var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
                var imgHeight = $(this).height();
                var imgWidth = $(this).width();
                $(this).parent()
                    .css("background-image", "url(" + imgSrc + ")")
                    .css("background-repeat","no-repeat")
                    .css("background-color","#fff")
                    .css("height", imgHeight + "px")
                    .css("width", imgWidth + "px");
                $(this).remove();
            });
            var $container=$('#main');
            $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $container.masonry({
                    itemSelector : '.box',
                    columnWidth: 200
                });
            });
            </script>
</body> <!-- just above the end of the body. In fact, this is said to be a good practice: leave the external js files in the head, and inline js at the end -->
```

Comment: Ah!  Okay, so now it appears to be working, except that all it does is shove everything over into a single column, not laying stuff out like it's supposed to...  Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Aaaand now now of the images are loading, after another refresh or two.  I see they're loading in the source, but not onscreen...  So it seems like there is a problem if I move the "rounded corners" function to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I've moved the rounded image code back to the top, but then Masonry stops working again...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does masonry needs the wrapping div? Can't you apply it directly to the images?

Comment: I'm not sure, honestly.  But I need it to play nice with the rounded-edges code.  Let me try it out though.

Comment: Okay, so, it turns out the JS for that is actually superfluous... As CSS works just fine to round the image edges.

So, here we are now, with only the Shadowbox.init, and the Masonry code, and Masonry is still not working.